# How to set values to a sharepoint list look up column in client object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How to set values to a sharepoint list look up column in client object model. how to convert a string value to a field look up type for setting value in a sharepoint list

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73252/sharepoint-client-model-and-setting-up-lookup-field

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify id from the lookup column.

```
 FieldLookupValue lv = new FieldLookupValue();
 lv.LookupId = 1;
 item["Project"] = lv;
 item.Update();
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```